# Linq performance for in-memory collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, linq, .net-4.0

I have a list: Collection users which has around 100K+ records of users (all user objects fully loaded from the database with fields like Bio, First name, last name etc). This collection is fetched on application start from the database and is kept in memory.

Then I have code like:

```
User cachedUser = users.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x.UserName, username,
StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Which I use to fetch users from this collection. But somehow I noticed that this operation is incredibly slow. Is there a performance issue while using Linq to query in memory collection of large objects? Should I instead call the DB each time I want to get a user?

Comment: You understand that `FirstOrDefault` is O(n), right?  If you have a very large collection, checking each item one by one will take some time.  (and dbs are usually indexed)   There are a variety of ways to speed this up, not least of which is to just throw it in a dictionary.  Is there a reason you're not doing that?

Comment: I want to cache all users thinking it would be better for performance reasons as GetUser() method is being called on almost each page of my application. If I use a dictionary, will it be much faster? Is dictionary O(1)? Or do I need to sort my dictionaory first?

Comment: Do you just need to cache the current user?  You can just use the built-in `Session` or `Cache` object for that.

Comment: @BryanCrosby No, I want to cache all the users not the current logged in user.

Comment: @RockySingh can you go to the database for once during login and save the details in Session. Access this session value in all pages. This will give you the Memory Management and Performance improvements.

Comment: Do you need *all* the users in memory *all* the time, or do you only need to handle, say, logged-in users? Most likely it's #2, in which case you should grab a single user from the database as needed - perhaps doing (per-user) session-caching of the individual user data.

Comment: I disagree with storing a list<> of 100,000 object sin the session.  I don't see how that would be a good thing when it comes to memory management.

Comment: @snemarch I need those users almost on every page. GetUser() method is being called and it doesnt matter whether the users are online or not. So I need all of them available in cache else multiple GetUser() hits to DB will be too costly for each page.

Comment: @scott.korin check my comment above. Do you still think I should not cache my users in memory when each page of my application hits the DB to fetch user details like first name, last name etc?

Comment: @RockySingh: do you need ALL users ALL the time on EVERY page? If not, cache a subset. If yes, there's either something horribly wrong with you architecture, or you're doing something very funky :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to optimize your response time and you could create a `Dictionary<T,U>` and search the user within:

```
    Dictionary<string, User> usersDictionary = new <Dictionary<string, User>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

    // After querying the users from the DB add them to the dictionary             
    usersDictionary.Add(user.UserName, user);

    // Then when you need to retrieve a user
    User retrieveUser = null; 
    usersDictionary.TryGetValue(username, out retrieveUser);
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: You probably mean `new Dictionary<string, User>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` since the question wants case insesitivity

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to load all users into a dictionary. That takes a lot of time and memory. Furthermore you have to synchronize access in case you change the data as well.

Comment: As I understand it he loads the data anyways. And it must not take a lot of time neither much memory if the objects have a low memory footprint. It would act like a cache in-memory with no network latency. It all depends on what the end goal is.

Comment: And he did not explain how the system should handle updates, so if he doesn't mind that there might be differences in the DB and in memory this might be a good solutions. It all depends on his real goal, which as I understand it is having all users in memory. And the best solution in this case is using a dictionary.

Comment: His final question is whether he should call the database on every call and I think yes. It's a user DB with 100k records and I can't believe they will never change. What if he wants to search for all users from a specific city? Your dictionary is only efficient when you search for username. In a database you can index more than one row

Comment: He did not express any other needs to search based on other properties. And if the columns don't get indexed the DB will take also more time (and you can't index on all columns). I am not against calling the DB. I just pointed out that if he needs an in-memory solution the best approach is to use a dictionary.

Comment: That was my statement as well. I agree with you solution, but I would never use it. And yes, you can set an index an all columns. Inserts and updates will be slower, but any selects will be fast. In any case better than storing 100k records in memory, which he will probably never use.

Answer (score 8):

I think you might need to re-think your architecture based on the information you have given us.  Take advantage of the database and let it do the search work for you.  Observe, measure, and make changes accordingly after that.  You might realize that you prematurely optimized the whole thing.

Answer (score 3):

Your LINQ query like any other iteration technique (loop, search in array) will access every single record until the requested record is found. In the worst case that means 100k comparisons. To make this faster, you have the following options:

1. use a sorted list or a dictionary: a binary search is a lot faster. Sort
   the data when fetching it from the database by using ORDER BY
2. use a DataSet. It's like an In-Memory database which provides faster search
3. Leave the data in the database and set appropriate indexes for faster access

I suggest to use the database due to the following reasons:

- It's a waste of memory to store 100k records, which you probably never use
- As soon as you change your data, you will have to refresh your cache, which might be rather complex
- web applications are multithreaded (every request runs in its own thread). In case you change your data, you will have to synchronize with locks.
- a database can cache frequently called data
- you have to write less code
- you have a stateless web application which scales better (web farms)
- your application probably has other data, you cannot store everything in memory

Comment: my problem is that with so many records even the DB access is slow. So I thought why not cache all users in-memory as I am already using events to manage the cached objects when a user updates his profile. Cant we index this in memory cache somehow?

Comment: What kind of database do you use? 100k records is not much, when set an index on the rows you are searching for. I would never keep so many records in memory within a web application.

Comment: 100K in our DB may soon reach 1M. Point is that no matter what RAM will always be faster than physical data files. So why not have some high performance algorithmic search in code which uses a RAM based collection instead of relying on DB?

Comment: Because the search in the DB is index based (binary) and not sequential. Because the DB will cache data in memory as well (probably in a more efficient way). And because you might want to change your data and you would have to synchronize it. Just don't do it! The access time to the DB should be a couple of milliseconds if it's designed well.

Comment: Caching 1M users in memory is a waste of memory that can be put to better use.  Even with 1M users a well optimized database should retrieve users in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

The different in the search performance that you notice is because the database is use indexing to locate the string in the database, but you in the memory you simple search all records until you find the one. Also the database keep a hash number for the string and search for this number hash that is a lot faster, and not make actually string compare.

The `Dictionary<>` make also an indexing, but have a delay to add data, when the data start grow because when its add some data, every time is search where to place it in the correct index point.

Also the database cache the results, many database cache also the indexing and create extra statistics that help to locate fast what you looking for.

Is better to let the database make the search, except if you can make something faster for extra custom cases.