# Caching strategy for better performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, caching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linq performance for in-memory collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124273/linq-performance-for-in-memory-collection)

I have a web application with around 1 million users. Almost every web page in that application calls the GetUser() method (to load first name in activity stream and other user details).
Right now I am hitting the database for each call, and I am thinking of caching all the users in memory and using Linq to fetch the search results or GetUser() from there.

My only issue is whether or not caching all users (in memory) is a good idea. Would I be wasting my RAM?
I personally think fetching from RAM is much faster than fetching from the DB (even if DB is optimized and indexed).

Note that I have already handled cache validation/updating/etc.

Does stackoverflow cache all its users?

Comment: Isn't this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124273/linq-performance-for-in-memory-collection/11124548#11124548

Comment: How much user data are you talking about? If it's just the user name and a few other fields, you might consider serializing it into the auth cookie, and then lazy loading the full user data from the db when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did something similar, but instead of turning to Linq, we just installed a copy of SQL Server Express on each web server. We would push user data changes to each of the web servers, and the local app was using a middle tier and only pulling data from the local database periodically (but at least that was local, instead of everyone hitting the database).

What technology you use for the caching, and how the app (or Linq) knows when to refresh its local copy, depends on how stale the cached data is allowed to be.

Comment: We are using events which fire on update etc to update the cache dynamically. For caching we are using in-memory .NET cache object.

Comment: Obviously hind-sight - but wouldn't you be better with a Cache server in this instance?

Comment: @Stuart Maybe? This was back in the 2000s before redis / memcached etc. had really matured. Even today a team might still choose the local DB approach because they wouldn't have to learn a new technology to implement / interact with. Both are still going to use the memory on the application server instead of any resources on the primary database server.

Comment: Oh totally, it was more for the people reading this in today's age, to give them a different approach based on what's now available.

Answer (score 1):

If GetUser will be returning the same set of users the majority of the time, and if most users will rarely be retrieved you might try a hybrid approach, where you setup a dictionary (or some other collection) and check that collection first and it does not exist then get it from the database and store it into the collection.

Using this approach you could also use the Cache since it already has built-in mechanisms to go stale and clean itself up.

Having said this, I worked on a project in the past where we did the same thing for users (we only had about 100 users though) and all our research and testing found it was faster to go to the database everytime.

Comment: You could also add some conditions to the collection so that the most frequent users are more likely to be in the collection than the users that log-in less frequently